# Pass props to higher-order stateless functional React component

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming

I would like to create a function that returns different versions of a stateless functional React component. My goal is to refactor this working code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-icons-kit';
import { socialFacebook, socialTwitter } from 'react-icons-kit/metrize';


export const FacebookIcon = ({ className, size }) => (
  <Icon
    icon={socialFacebook}
    size={size}
    className={className}
  />
);

export const TwitterIcon = ({ className, size }) => (
  <Icon
    icon={socialTwitter}
    size={size}
    className={className}
  />
);
```

Into something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-icons-kit';
import { socialFacebook, socialTwitter } from 'react-icons-kit/metrize';


const ProtoIcon = ({ icon }) => ({ className, icon, size }) => (
  <Icon
    className={className}
    icon={icon}
    size={size}
  />
);

export const FacebookIcon = ProtoIcon(socialFacebook);
export const TwitterIcon = ProtoIcon(socialTwitter);
```

However, the above fails and the problem seems to be that `icon` isn't passed on to the returned function. What is the best way to solve this? Reading the React manual on HOC's, I suppose this could be done by returning a class that extends `React.component` but I really like the form that I've tried above. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do in a functional-ish way?

Thanks!

EDIT1: To clarify, my final API would be `(<FacebookIcon size={32} className="some-class">)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. FacebookIcon and TwitterIcon need to be converted to stateless components so that we can pass props into it. You've just created a variable reference to the ProtoIcon component that doesn't, unfortunately, return the JSX when used.

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Icon } from 'react-icons-kit';
import { socialFacebook, socialTwitter } from 'react-icons-kit/metrize';

const ProtoIcon = (icon, props) => (
  <Icon icon={icon} {...props} />
);

export const FacebookIcon = (props) => ProtoIcon(socialFacebook, props);
export const TwitterIcon = (props) => ProtoIcon(socialTwitter, props);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FacebookIcon size={32} className="some-class" />
      <TwitterIcon size={32} className="some-class"/>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```